# Python code to change displayed image with pyqt4 on request

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have the following code to display am image using pyQt:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtGui.QMainWindow()

window.setGeometry(opts.posx, opts.posy, opts.width, opts.height)

pic = QtGui.QLabel(window)
pic.setGeometry(5, 5, opts.width-10, opts.height-10)
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(opts.filename)
pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(opts.height)
pic.setPixmap(pixmap)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would like to wrap up this code possibly in the form of a class, and be able to set a different image during runtime, using signals, socket, threads I really do not know. I would imagine something like:

```
class MyImage(object):
   def __init(self, args):
       some setup code
       self.pic = whatever
   def set_image(self, filename):
       pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(opts.filename)
       pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(opts.height)
       pic.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

With the original code I just call `sys.exit(app.exec_())` which makes the code 'freeze'. But I want to send a signal (and a filename) from a different running python code. Any suggestion how this can be handled easily and straightforward? Maybe overwriting the `app.exec_` method?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class ImageChanger(QtGui.QWidget):    
    def __init__(self, images, parent=None):
        super(ImageChanger, self).__init__(parent)        

        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.addItems(images)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.comboBox)

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, images, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)

        self.imageChanger = ImageChanger(images)
        self.imageChanger.move(self.imageChanger.pos().y(), self.imageChanger.pos().x() + 100)
        self.imageChanger.show()
        self.imageChanger.comboBox.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.changeImage)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def changeImage(self, pathToImage):
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(pathToImage)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    images = [  "/path/to/image/1",
                "/path/to/image/2",
                "/path/to/image/3",
                ]

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow(images)
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Even if some time has gone by, I need a code which takes the filename from the outside, not hardcoded inside. I would like to 'send' the filename of the image to display to the code.

Comment: @Alex That's an easy fix, check out my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14368034/1006989)